# My application force closes when trying to switch launchers on Android 5.0

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to create an application to change the launcher on an Android device using the following function:

```
private void changeLauncher() {
    getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());
    Intent selector = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    selector.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");                          
    selector.setComponent(new ComponentName("android", "com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity"));
    startActivity(selector);

}
```

It works for all Android devices but force closes on the LG G3 running Android 5.0. However it does work for another Android 5.0 device (Asus K19 Fonepad). What can i do to solve it ?

Comment: Please show your Logcat error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method to:

```
private void changeLauncher() {
    getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());
    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(selector);
}
```

You seem to be trying to launch the chooser activity directly, rather than specifying an `Intent` and letting Android populate the list of activities itself, which is the correct usage of the resolver.

Comment: I don't know why it would work only on some devices, but it was definitely not the right way of doing it. Glad I could help solve your issue though.